# How do I create css class in createMuiTheme() and use them directly without having to get its value from component "classes" props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to avoid typing redundant code. In multiple components I have created the same css classes. I want to add them to the theme using createMuiTheme() and then only using the style directly from the theme without having to call "classes" props on the Component props.

I have tried creating a theme on the root Component like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette:{
      primary: {
        main: '#47286E',
        light: '#D91677'
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#9156D8' 
      },
  },

 fab: {
    position: "relative",
    top: 0,
    marginTop: 20px
    textTransform: 'none',
    width: 220,
    height: 50
  },

});
```

then I passed theme down to the other components using

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

I tried importing the fab button directly inside the component

```
<Fab variant="extended" className={this.props.theme.fab} size='small'>
    Change
</Fab>
```

however I don't seem to get any value when I try to get fab css class. I just don't want to create a whole new

```
const styles = theme => {
    blabbla
}
```

and import it in every component using the "classes" props if what I want is already on the theme being passed down to its child components.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `createMuiTheme` is meant for that.

Alternatively you could just create a style object that you want to reuse

```
const styles = {
  fab: {
    position: "relative",
    top: 0,
    marginTop: 20px
    textTransform: 'none',
    width: 220,
    height: 50
  }
};
```

And just import and use it wherever you need to

```
import fabStyles from '../../somewhere-everyone-can-get-it.js';
import styles from './styles-for-this-component.js';

...

withStyles({...fabStyles, ...styles})(Component);
```

If you need the theme and styles.

```
withTheme(withStyles({...fabStyles, ...styles})(Component));
```

You can also use `recompose` to clean this up.

Comment: but how can I have access to the theme variable inside of these separate files?

Comment: I don't see you using theme styles in your example, but you can use the `withTheme` HOC in addition to `withStyles`

Comment: can u please give me an example using codebox or something? Im still getting the hang of using HOC.... thank you!

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: I am sorry @Galupuf, but when I use it this way: withRouter(withTheme(withStyles({...defaultStyles, ...styles})(TableCustom))); it stops showing the whole component for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186116/discussion-between-galupuf-and-jeff-goes).

Answer (score 1):

`className={this.props.theme.fab}` doesn't work because `this.props.theme.fab` is an object, not a class name. When `withStyles` is used, it takes care of generating a unique class name (e.g. available via `props.classes.fab`) as well as injecting the CSS for that class into the head of the document. The `fab` object in your theme has not had this work done for it.

The code below shows a couple ways you can avoid redundant code. The first is a `withFab` function that encapsulates the CSS and the call to `withStyles`.

The second uses the `fab` object more directly and just passes it to the `style` property rather than the `className` property. You could get the styles from `theme.fab` (rather than a separate js file) similar to your initial approach, but there isn't necessarily a reason to put this in your theme unless you care about being able to override it via different `MuiThemeProviders` in your rendering hierarchy.

There are a couple downsides to the second (style property) approach:

- If you use this on a lot of different elements, the CSS is redundantly specified in the DOM on each of those elements.
- It won't support CSS that requires classes (e.g. using pseudo elements like :hover)

So I would recommend something more similar to the first option (`UseWithFab/withFab`) shown below.

`withFab.js`

```
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

const styles = {
  fab: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  }
};
export const fabStyles = {
  backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
};
const withFab = component => {
  return withStyles(styles)(component);
};
export default withFab;
```

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import withFab, { fabStyles } from "./withFab";

const UseWithFab = withFab(props => {
  return <div className={props.classes.fab}>Using withFab</div>;
});
const UseFabStyles = props => {
  return <div style={fabStyles}>Using fabStyles</div>;
};
function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <UseWithFab />
      <UseFabStyles />
    </>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit 0xlk0vxmxn]

Answer (score 0):

These are good answers.  I'm taking notes :)  When I first read the post, I suspect the intuition was around using the `overrides` key in the built-in MUI theme.

I often find the overrides key a more convenient way to implement a format used "more often" in the app.

It's a two-step process:

1. Decide which MUI component you want to modify
2. Set the `className` prop using a naming convention that works for you

```
import clsx from 'clsx'; // not required, but handy in the long-run
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';

const Component = () => {
  ...
  return <Fab className=clsx('MyCustomFab') />
}
```

```js
// my theme prop for the MUI <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme} />

export default createMuiTheme({
  ...
  overrides: {
    MuiFab: {
      root: {
        '&.MyCustomFab': { // note: the "no-space" => MuiFab AND ...
          backgroundColor: "lightblue",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```